# Is an EU residency permit for EU nationals a valid travel document within the EU?

Tags: regulations, eu

I am a citizen of an EU member state, being a resident in another EU member state. I hold a both a national identity card of my birth country and a resident permit of my home country. In an answer to an earlier question I asked about traveling to the UK with an almost invalid national identity card  it was [mentioned](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21933/141) that at least in the UK I should be given "every reasonable opportunity” to prove I am an EEA national. Given that information is printed on my resident permit, I am wondering to what extend such a resident permit is a valid travel document to travel within the EU.

Comment: Being given “every reasonable opportunity” to prove your citizenship is not UK-specific but based on EU law.

Comment: Again, the point is that you don't require a *travel* document at all, just to establish your nationality…

Answer (score 7):

You can enter any EU/EEA member country as long as you can prove your nationality by any means, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identity_cards_in_the_European_Economic_Area#use):

> Strictly speaking, it is not necessary for an EEA or Swiss citizen to possess a valid national identity card or passport to enjoy the right of free movement. In theory, if an EEA or Swiss citizen can prove his/her nationality by any other means (e.g. by presenting an expired national identity card or passport, or a citizenship certificate) he/she must be permitted to enter and reside in the EEA and Switzerland without a visa.

As you can see, as long as you can prove your nationaly *by any means* then you can travel to any EU/EEA country. Of course presenting a valid passport or national ID card should make things easier but any other document would work as well.

Comment: It may make the difference between 15 seconds at immigration while they scan your passport, vs a 6 hour epic with lots of questioning and waiting...

Comment: Even if valid travel documents are not strictly required for an EU, EEA or CH citizen to *enter* UK, are they not required to exit the Schengen area? That is Andra's first issue before facing the problem how to enter the UK.