# Travelling back to the UK after naturalisation without a UK passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, dual-nationality

I have a dual Polish [1] and British citizenship, but no British passport yet. If I have to leave the UK now (using my old Polish passport), will I have any problems coming back into the UK?

[1] Poland is an EU member (believe it or not :D)

Comment: You won't have any problems.

Comment: You can bring (copies of) your naturalisation papers, but as Polish person you can spend any time you want in the UK.

Comment: @Willeke although true as far as I know you need to enter the country of your nationality as that national. So in this case entering Poland as Polish and entering Britain as British.

Comment: Even if you have two passports, usually you should use the same passport leaving and entering.

Comment: So before I get my British passport, I could use the Polish one exclusively and it would be OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was in exactly the same circumstances and I managed to enter the UK without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following answer - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21936/42483

You can enter **any EU/EEA country** (which includes the UK for the next 2+ years definitely) without an ID card or passport as long as you can prove your nationality with whatever means.

The only difference is whether it takes you less than a minute to walk through immigration or quite longer (as they would need to establish that you are actually the citizen you are claiming to be).

P.S. In theory this should apply to any country in the world.

Comment: Trying to board a flight using a driver's license and birth certificate will almost certainly end in failure.

Comment: @jacoman891 Well true, although in OP's case he can board the plane using his Polish ID (as you can travel to any EU/EEA country being Polish) to reach Britain and then do the magic to prove he's British.

Comment: true, true. I was merely commenting on the discrepancy between the rules and the reality in these matters...

Comment: Entering and reaching a country can be very different matters. :)
In some cases (no passport, flying) you can enter but not reach the country, in other (passport, not-flying, no visa or something) you can reach the country but not eligible to enter it.