# Can I travel from France to UK with a recently expired French passport?

Tags: uk, france, passports

I'm a **French national**, with a **recently expired passport** (expired 1 month ago) and no national ID card. I'd like to **go to London from Paris** (by bus, if it matters). **Can I do so with my expired passport?**

The reason I even ask is that, in France and (I heard) many European countries, a passport expired for less than 5 years is a valid proof of ID.

Comment: Be ready to be questioned or maybe even turned back too. UKBA is quite strict on stuffs like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is more or less given in two related [travel.se](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21932/can-you-travel-to-the-uk-with-an-eu-national-identity-card-that-is-only-valid-fo) [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21935/is-an-eu-residency-permit-for-eu-nationals-a-valid-travel-document-within-the-eu). So in theory you should be able to travel to the UK with a recently expired passport. However, as it is mentioned in the comments, do expect issues.

You might also be denied boarding, by either the ferry or carrier, since they have to bring you back when denied entry.

Comment: By ferry might be easier, as they typically have juxtaposed border controls, so you'd clear UK immigration before boarding the ferry. If they let you through, the ferry company will be fine as you'd already be "in" the UK by the time you boarded

Comment: Are ferries generally forced to bring you back? On what basis?

Comment: @gagravarr Are you sure that is the case with all ferries?

Comment: @Annoyed Laws! Andra - Not all ferries to the UK have it, but the [main French ports do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_Border_Agency#Juxtaposed_controls)

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes, but my question was which ones? I know there is an international convention for air transport, there are certainly some local laws here and there but I am not aware of any general framework for ferries or cruise ships. There could be one, though.